# Can Timer Threads be Viewed in VS'17 Debug Mode?

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio, debugging, system.timers.timer

I am trying to make sure my program is not causing a "thread tree" scenario by continuing timers, and opening new Timers (threads) as they cycle... if that makes sense. 
Nevertheless, my main question is exactly as it sounds; 
I do know how to, and already have open, the thread view in Visual Studios 2017, but none of the threads opened by Timer elapse events are showing up in the thread view. 
I don't imagine it has anything to do with the matter, seeing as Timers are the System.Timers - but this project is built from within Unity3D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this with a Unity3D application but I expect that threads created by a System.Timers.Timer will show up in the Threads window. After all, they are just background threads created in a particular way. You should be able to verify this very easily: Place a breakpoint in the method that gets called by the timer thread. When hit you will see the thread in the Threads window. Continue and the thread will disappear, based on what you describe.

Comment: Yeah, the threads show up with a breakpoint. thanks man..... now to learn how to manage the thread viewer... that crap be super confusing and seemingly random. XD (but I'll get it soon enough) 

Appreciate the assistance. (seriously, most people I get responses from on Stack are complete D-Bags for some reason. :| lol! )